# malloc'd memory and sigsegv

Tags: c, linux, malloc

help me in understanding the malloc behaviour..   my code is as follows::

```
    int main()
    {   
    int *ptr=NULL;
    ptr=(int *)malloc(1);
    //check for malloc
    *ptr=1000;

    printf("address of ptr is %p and value of ptr is %d\n",ptr,*ptr);
    return 0;
    }
```

the  above program works fine(runs without error)...how?? as I have supplied a value of 1000 in 1 byte only!!

Am I overwriting the next memory addresss in heap? 
if yes, then why not sigsgev is there?

Comment: The behavior is undefined, so it might or might not crash. In some implementations, the program will crash when you `free(ptr)`.

Comment: Has it got to do something with packing ?? Typically the default packing on 4 bytes with a 32 bit app.

Answer (score 2):

Many implementations of `malloc` will allocate at a certain "resolution" for efficiency.

That means that, even though you *asked* for one byte, you may well have gotten 16 or 32.

However, it's not something you can rely on since it's undefined behaviour.

Undefined behaviour means that *anything* can happen, including the whole thing working despite the problematic code :-)

Comment: sir, (may be this a stupid question..but i need to ask)..
what is meant by "many implementation of malloc"???
to all those ppl who uses gcc n glibc (downloaded from the standard website..) implementation/definition must be the same...na??
n
isn't there a standard definition for the functions like malloc, free etc??

Comment: @saurabh: yes, gcc (or mor correctly glibc) may have a particular implementation but that's not the only one. MSVC has its own, IBMs xlc has another and so on. GLibC is only _one_ implementation. And, yes, the ISO C standard specifies the definition but it generally covers _behaviour_ rather than _implementation._

Comment: Most `malloc` implementations are asking heap memory from the operating system (usually the kernel, thru a system call) in much larger chunks (typically, several pages of 4Kbytes). On Linux, `malloc` would probably sometimes use the `mmap` (and possibly `sbrk`) syscall to request a "large chunk" of memory from kernel. Then the implementation of `malloc` would cut that chunk in smaller pieces, etc etc.... As usual, the evil is in the details.

Comment: TO learn more about make, you can look at the header of malloc. Also, you can go one using the memory from ptr ... onwards till you get a crash for a crash at ptr+x. x is your granularity for malloc user library you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Using a debug heap you will definitely get a crash or some other notification when you freed the memory (but you didn't call free).

Segmentation faults are for page-level access violations, and a memory page is usually on the order of 4k, so an overrun by 3 bytes isn't likely to be detected until some finer grained check detects it or some other part of your code crashes because you overwrote some memory with 'garbage'